# Weighted Stratified Sampling without replacement Pyspark; multiple limits

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, key, sampling

I have two dataframes df1 and df2. Below are samples:

df1:

```
    LSOA    SEX AGE LADY    COUNT  WEIGHT
    E9001    1  0   D0901     7    0.045
    E9001    1  0   D0901     5    0.34
    E9002    1  0   D0901     13   0.062
    E9002    1  0   D0901     2    0.12
    E9003    1  0   D0901     9    0.024
    E9001    1  1   D0901     8    0.11
    E9001    1  1   D0901     3    0.027
    E9002    1  1   D0901     4    0.67
    E9002    1  1   D0901     12   0.029
    E9003    1  1   D0901     1    0.084
    E9001    1  2   D0901     21   0.19
    E9001    1  2   D0901     11   0.45
    E9002    1  2   D0901     9    0.078
    E9002    1  2   D0901     5    0.029
    E9003    1  2   D0901     24   0.49
    E9001    2  0   D0901     18   0.062
    E9001    2  0   D0901     10   0.12
    E9002    2  0   D0901     14   0.0126
    E9002    2  0   D0901     4    0.52
    E9003    2  0   D0901     31   0.0769
    E9001    2  1   D0901     6    0.107
    E9001    2  1   D0901     8    0.075
    E9002    2  1   D0901     9    0.029
    E9002    2  1   D0901     15   0.081
    E9003    2  1   D0901     4    0.31
    E9001    2  2   D0901     10   0.049
    E9001    2  2   D0901     19   0.51
    E9002    2  2   D0901     9    0.074
    E9002    2  2   D0901     2    0.18
    E9003    2  2   D0901     18   0.073
    E9004    1  0   D0902     14   0.017
    E9004    1  0   D0902     2    0.085
    E9005    1  0   D0902     16   0.72
    E9005    1  0   D0902     15   0.13
    E9006    1  0   D0902     1    0.031
    E9004    1  1   D0902     2    0.162
    E9004    1  1   D0902     17   0.041
    E9005    1  1   D0902     14   0.698
    E9005    1  1   D0902     3    0.0932
    E9006    1  1   D0902     4    0.62
    E9004    1  2   D0902     31   0.0231
    E9004    1  2   D0902     21   0.237
    E9004    1  2   D0902     2    0.019
    E9005    1  2   D0902     0    0.17
    E9005    1  2   D0902     19   0.017
    E9006    1  2   D0902     38   0.371
    E9011    2  0   D0902     24   0.619
    E9011    2  0   D0902     51   0.926
    E9012    2  0   D0902     11   0.097
    E9012    2  0   D0902     41   0.48
    E9014    2  0   D0902     2    0.093
    E9011    2  1   D0902     20   0.017
    E9011    2  1   D0902     21   0.19
    E9012    2  1   D0902     41   0.38
    E9012    2  1   D0902     27   0.042
    E9014    2  1   D0902     52   0.18
    E9011    2  2   D0902     17   0.254
    E9011    2  2   D0902     38   0.0721
    E9012    2  2   D0902     4    0.623
    E9012    2  2   D0902     19   0.0389
    E9014    2  2   D0902     44   0.25
```

and dataframe df2:

```
LADY   SEX AGE  N
D0901   1   0   1
D0901   1   1   0
D0901   1   2   2
D0901   2   0   3
D0901   2   1   1
D0902   1   0   4
D0902   1   1   1
D0902   1   2   2
D0902   2   0   3
D0902   2   1   1
```

where LADY, SEX, AGE columns are the stratum (keys) and WEIGHT are values each between 0.0 and 1.0.

I wish to take N samples of strata = [LADY, SEX, AGE] of df1, without replacement using df2 as multiple keys (the strata).

Is there a way of doing this stratified sampling without replacement, using the column WEIGHT as the probability of that strata (or row) of being included in the samples, using pyspark?

So I end up with a dataframe df3, on N rows of df1 per strata.

I understand that pyspark uses fractions instead of integers and that for each sample a limit can be applied. However I wish to have different limits for each strata using the N column in df2.

I hope this makes sense. Many thanks.

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by 'using the column WEIGHT as the probability of that strata (or row) of being included in the samples'

for example in the fourth strata
LADY   SEX AGE 
D0901  2      0  

You have 5 potential records with weights (0.062, 0.12, 0.0126, 0.52, 0.0769). Do you want the record with a weight of 0.12 to appear in 12% of all samples? if so the average sample will only contain .7915 records not 3. Did you want to increase the probability proportionally? in which case the record with weight 0.52 would want to appear in 197% of all samples which isn't possible.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The WEIGHT column should be standardised to 1.0 for each strata so the closer the number is to 1.0, the higher the chances of that row, in the strata is, of being included in the sample.